# Detox: how to test multiline TextInput

Tags: react-native, keyboard, hide, detox

I'm trying to use detox to test a form in my react-native app.

One of the inputs in the form has `multiline={true}`.

I am trying to run the following test:

```
const inputElement = element(by.id('input_multiline'));
await expect(inputElement).toBeVisible();
await inputElement.typeText('line1\n');
await inputElement.typeText('line2\n');
await inputElement.typeText('line3\n');

const submitElement = element(by.id('submit'));
await submitElement.toBeVisible();
await submitElement.tap();
```

This test fails to pass 75% visibility criteria, because the keyboard is hiding the submit button.

Normally for TextInput with `multiline={false}` you can just append `\n` to the input string automatically moving to the next stage, but for multiline input `\n` just adds a new line.

What can I do in order to pass this test in detox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we need to be able to dismiss the keyboard for TextInput with `multiline={true}`.

For this we are going to make use of Keyboard module from react-native.

```
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native'
```

Now wrap your form with TouchableWithoutFeedback and call Keyboard.dismiss() on press.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
  { /* your form goes here */ }
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Now modify your detox test to dismiss the keyboard.

```
const inputElement = element(by.id('input'));
await expect(inputElement).toBeVisible();
await inputElement.typeText('line1\n');
await inputElement.typeText('line2\n');
await inputElement.typeText('line3\n');
// click somewhere outside the input
await inputElement.tapAtPoint({x: 0, y: 1});

const submitElement = element(by.id('submit'));
await submitElement.toBeVisible();
await submitElement.tap();
```

[image: detox running the test]