# Detox - Can't locate the element on the screen

Tags: testing, react-native, detox

[image: screen]

I tried to resolve the issue of [Detox - Enter on Numpad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766371/detox-enter-on-numpad/47825605#47825605) and thus leading to this issue.

According to the screen, I have an input field with number. So there is no enter key or typeText '\n' to enter it. So I think of the solution to tap on the header to hide the keyboard. However, even though the header is there. with the testID = {..._screen_header_}

It still give me an error of

"Recovery Suggestion" : "Check if the element exists in the UI hierarchy printed below. If it exists, adjust the matcher so that it accurately matches element."
       }

```
   Error Trace: [
     {
       "Description" : "Interaction cannot continue because the desired element was not found.",
       "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
       "Error Code" : "0",
       "File Name" : "GREYElementInteraction.m",
       "Function Name" : "-[GREYElementInteraction matchedElementsWithTimeout:error:]",
       "Line" : "124"
     }
   ]
```

**Steps to Reproduce**
just have a header or any element, because this issue happens at one place that it couldn't locate the screen as well. Which means the detox framework couldn't locate the item.

Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions
Detox: 5.10
Node: 8.7.0
Device: iPhone 7
Xcode: 9.1
macOS: 10.13.2

Comment: Hi. Can you please post your detox test code too? thanks

Comment: Hi @Antoni4,

`await waitForAppear('${screen_id}_screen_header');
await expectAppear('${screen_id}_screen_header');` with the waitForAppear is `return waitFor(element(by.id(elementId))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(30000);` and the expectAppear is `expect(element(by.id(elementId))).toBeVisible();`. According to what I understand the framework doing, this would be correct? Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: [---->the error about visibility<----](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8481265/34545935-947ddddc-f144-11e7-9f2e-7b63180831ab.png). The header is right there right? Why it couldn't be located?

Comment: I think I know what the problem is, but I need to see your header code. Any chance you can post the code for your header file? Also are you using react-navigation?

Comment: Also when you click on the header yourself, does it hide the keyboard? i.e. is the header element actually clickable?

Comment: [----->header_tag<-----](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8481265/34548670-73325136-f157-11e7-92de-cfc749a9f7a5.png). this is how I did for the header. I created a different component

Comment: and the component would be [---->header_component<----](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8481265/34548885-9f3fdc7a-f158-11e7-9a54-cb5775658161.png)

Comment: For the keyboard. I tried to locate the header first before I click. So that I make sure that the element is there to be clicked. But then because that I can't locate it. So I haven't tried the pressing just yet. Thanks @Antoni4. Besides. I have the scrollview there but It couldn't locate the scrollview either. It seems like all the view has been blocked from locating. It is all about the visibility. But funny thing is it doesn't happen for every screen. just some screen? which is really weird.

Comment: And we use [react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux)

Comment: Okay I'll post what I think is going wrong a bit later

Comment: Hi @Antoni4, Is everything okay? Is there any update on this issue? Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you trying to click on the whole header (green background) or just the smaller header element (white background)? Because in your test you are using '${screen_id}_screen_header' as element ID, but you are passing 'header_' into your header component.

Comment: I also can't see anything that makes your HeaderMedium component touchable. Can you wrap it with a touchable, and make it fire an alert box when pressed? Then try pressing it and see if it actually triggers the alert message to appear. I'm just trying to understand if there are any hidden overlays covering your HeaderMedium component.

Comment: hi @Antoni4, I changed the Id accordingly, but the issue is still there. For the clicking part, I only click if I see the element, that is the process of clicking that I think would be the best practice, because you can't click the think before it appear right? the issue of this Thread is that somehow I can't locate the header in this screen. And there is a scrollview as well, but I can't locate the scroll view either. If that makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: I also encountered issues around locating scroll views, mainly when they are nested. Just because a component is visible to you doesn't mean it's visible to detox. For example I can give you code sample where a transparent overlay covering a button will fail a click test because of the visibility criteria.

Comment: Can you provide a working code example to this problem? Maybe through github? It will be a lot easier to solve.

Comment: @Antoni4, I will try to put a code example as soon as possible. But I thought locating and clicking are 2 different things, right?

Comment: that will be awesome thanks. Will make it a lot easier to solve. As far as I know in order for click to occur the visibility criteria has to be satisfied.